# How to make calculations between rows with the same ID in a dataframe and add to new columns, using python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, pandas-groupby

I have a list of locations with coordinates and NETWORK_ID.My dataframe looks like;

```
SC  NETWORK_ID  Lat         Lon  
0   ED0002      41.6742     26.553130600000003  
0   ED0016      41.7750556  26.9170278  
0   IS0030      41.05455556 28.80925  
0   IS0134      40.97616944 28.80165  
1   ED0016      41.7750556  26.9170278  
1   IS0096      40.99406111 28.82413056  
1   IS0137      40.98033889 28.73052778  
1   IS0280      41.1085556  28.874861100000004  
2   ED0002      41.6742     26.553130600000003  
2   ED0018      41.26675    26.687669399999997  
2   IS0034      41.10741944 28.80134167  
2   IS0063      40.97868889 28.72448889  
2   IS0280      41.1085556  28.874861100000004  
2   IS0880      41.03519444 28.82001389  
3   ED0018      41.26675    26.687669399999997  
3   IB9048      40.98021667 28.833175  
3   IS0034      41.10741944 28.80134167  
3   IS0063      40.97868889 28.72448889  
3   IS0280      41.1085556  28.874861100000004
```

I'd like to calculate distances between the locations with the same 'SC', and add to new columns.
I planned;

> distance between WED0002-WED0016 to column Neig1
> distance between WED0002-WED0030 to column Neig2
> distance between WED0002-WED0134 to column Neig3
> distance between WED0016-WED0030 to column Neig1
> distance between WED0016-WED0134 to column Neig2

code for geographical distance calculation:

```
def global_distance(location1, location2):
    lat1, lon1 = location1
    lat2, lon2 = location2
    radius = 6371 # radius of the Earth

    dlat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
    dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
    a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) \
    * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    d = radius * c

    return d
```

Answer (score 1):

From comments you can see how I've built this up

1. use `itertools.combinations` to get pairs of *NETWORK_ID* within an *SC*
2. then some `explode()` to transform this list of pairs into rows
3. split out pairs into columns so the can be used in `merge()`
4. all prep done - use `geopy.distance` to calculate distance

From your sample data I couldn't see the mapping to the columns you stated you wanted.  Everything is simple now you have all valid combinations and the distances between them.

```
import itertools
import geopy.distance

data = """SC  NETWORK_ID  Lat         Lon  
0   ED0002      41.6742     26.553130600000003  
0   ED0016      41.7750556  26.9170278  
0   IS0030      41.05455556 28.80925  
0   IS0134      40.97616944 28.80165  
1   ED0016      41.7750556  26.9170278  
1   IS0096      40.99406111 28.82413056  
1   IS0137      40.98033889 28.73052778  
1   IS0280      41.1085556  28.874861100000004  
2   ED0002      41.6742     26.553130600000003  
2   ED0018      41.26675    26.687669399999997  
2   IS0034      41.10741944 28.80134167  
2   IS0063      40.97868889 28.72448889  
2   IS0280      41.1085556  28.874861100000004  
2   IS0880      41.03519444 28.82001389  
3   ED0018      41.26675    26.687669399999997  
3   IB9048      40.98021667 28.833175  
3   IS0034      41.10741944 28.80134167  
3   IS0063      40.97868889 28.72448889  
3   IS0280      41.1085556  28.874861100000004 """
a = [[i for i in l.split(" ") if i!=""] for l in data.split("\n")]
df = pd.DataFrame(a[1:], columns=a[0])
# first get pairs of neigbors within SC
dfd = ( df.groupby("SC").agg({"NETWORK_ID":lambda s: list(itertools.combinations(list(s), 2))})
    # generate rows for each pair
    .explode("NETWORK_ID").rename({"NETWORK_ID":"PAIR"}, axis=1).reset_index()
    # split pairs of locations back into individual column s
    .assign(n1=lambda dfa: dfa["PAIR"].apply(lambda s: s[0]),
            n2=lambda dfa: dfa["PAIR"].apply(lambda s: s[1]))
    # merge back original data so have lat/lon for the pair of locations
    .merge(df, left_on=["SC","n1"], right_on=["SC","NETWORK_ID"]).drop("NETWORK_ID", axis=1)
    .merge(df, left_on=["SC","n2"], right_on=["SC","NETWORK_ID"]).drop("NETWORK_ID", axis=1)
    # finally calc the distance
    .assign(miles=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: 
                                           geopy.distance.geodesic((r["Lat_x"],r["Lon_x"]), 
                                                                   (r["Lat_y"],r["Lon_y"])).miles, axis=1)) )

print(dfd.to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
SC              PAIR      n1      n2        Lat_x               Lon_x        Lat_y               Lon_y       miles
 0  (ED0002, ED0016)  ED0002  ED0016      41.6742  26.553130600000003   41.7750556          26.9170278   20.060612
 0  (ED0002, IS0030)  ED0002  IS0030      41.6742  26.553130600000003  41.05455556            28.80925  124.842785
 0  (ED0016, IS0030)  ED0016  IS0030   41.7750556          26.9170278  41.05455556            28.80925  110.157080
 0  (ED0002, IS0134)  ED0002  IS0134      41.6742  26.553130600000003  40.97616944            28.80165  126.496404
 0  (ED0016, IS0134)  ED0016  IS0134   41.7750556          26.9170278  40.97616944            28.80165  112.408698
 0  (IS0030, IS0134)  IS0030  IS0134  41.05455556            28.80925  40.97616944            28.80165    5.423670
 1  (ED0016, IS0096)  ED0016  IS0096   41.7750556          26.9170278  40.99406111         28.82413056  112.821672
 1  (ED0016, IS0137)  ED0016  IS0137   41.7750556          26.9170278  40.98033889         28.73052778  109.054636
 1  (IS0096, IS0137)  IS0096  IS0137  40.99406111         28.82413056  40.98033889         28.73052778    4.985179
 1  (ED0016, IS0280)  ED0016  IS0280   41.7750556          26.9170278   41.1085556  28.874861100000004  111.584270
 1  (IS0096, IS0280)  IS0096  IS0280  40.99406111         28.82413056   41.1085556  28.874861100000004    8.333445
 1  (IS0137, IS0280)  IS0137  IS0280  40.98033889         28.73052778   41.1085556  28.874861100000004   11.625086
 2  (ED0002, ED0018)  ED0002  ED0018      41.6742  26.553130600000003     41.26675  26.687669399999997   28.972852
 2  (ED0002, IS0034)  ED0002  IS0034      41.6742  26.553130600000003  41.10741944         28.80134167  123.206273
 2  (ED0018, IS0034)  ED0018  IS0034     41.26675  26.687669399999997  41.10741944         28.80134167  110.732410
 2  (ED0002, IS0063)  ED0002  IS0063      41.6742  26.553130600000003  40.97868889         28.72448889  122.724622
 2  (ED0018, IS0063)  ED0018  IS0063     41.26675  26.687669399999997  40.97868889         28.72448889  108.125677
 2  (IS0034, IS0063)  IS0034  IS0063  41.10741944         28.80134167  40.97868889         28.72448889    9.748491
 2  (ED0002, IS0280)  ED0002  IS0280      41.6742  26.553130600000003   41.1085556  28.874861100000004  126.809654
 2  (ED0018, IS0280)  ED0018  IS0280     41.26675  26.687669399999997   41.1085556  28.874861100000004  114.537975
 2  (IS0034, IS0280)  IS0034  IS0280  41.10741944         28.80134167   41.1085556  28.874861100000004    3.838056
 2  (IS0063, IS0280)  IS0063  IS0280  40.97868889         28.72448889   41.1085556  28.874861100000004   11.917612
 2  (ED0002, IS0880)  ED0002  IS0880      41.6742  26.553130600000003  41.03519444         28.82001389  125.846863
 2  (ED0018, IS0880)  ED0018  IS0880     41.26675  26.687669399999997  41.03519444         28.82001389  112.361444
 2  (IS0034, IS0880)  IS0034  IS0880  41.10741944         28.80134167  41.03519444         28.82001389    5.078493
 2  (IS0063, IS0880)  IS0063  IS0880  40.97868889         28.72448889  41.03519444         28.82001389    6.335481
 2  (IS0280, IS0880)  IS0280  IS0880   41.1085556  28.874861100000004  41.03519444         28.82001389    5.816514
 3  (ED0018, IB9048)  ED0018  IB9048     41.26675  26.687669399999997  40.98021667           28.833175  113.685179
 3  (ED0018, IS0034)  ED0018  IS0034     41.26675  26.687669399999997  41.10741944         28.80134167  110.732410
 3  (IB9048, IS0034)  IB9048  IS0034  40.98021667           28.833175  41.10741944         28.80134167    8.933948
 3  (ED0018, IS0063)  ED0018  IS0063     41.26675  26.687669399999997  40.97868889         28.72448889  108.125677
 3  (IB9048, IS0063)  IB9048  IS0063  40.98021667           28.833175  40.97868889         28.72448889    5.684762
 3  (IS0034, IS0063)  IS0034  IS0063  41.10741944         28.80134167  40.97868889         28.72448889    9.748491
 3  (ED0018, IS0280)  ED0018  IS0280     41.26675  26.687669399999997   41.1085556  28.874861100000004  114.537975
 3  (IB9048, IS0280)  IB9048  IS0280  40.98021667           28.833175   41.1085556  28.874861100000004    9.120037
 3  (IS0034, IS0280)  IS0034  IS0280  41.10741944         28.80134167   41.1085556  28.874861100000004    3.838056
 3  (IS0063, IS0280)  IS0063  IS0280  40.97868889         28.72448889   41.1085556  28.874861100000004   11.917612
```

### supplementary update

Need to deal with edge case where an *SC* has only one *NETWORK_CELLID*.  Generate a synthetic `tuple` to itself.

```
df = pd.read_csv("3G_Cell_File_.cel", sep="\t")
mycols = ['NETWORK_CELLID', 'SC', 'Lat', 'Lon']
# de-duplicate no point in calculating distance many times...
dfdd = df.loc[:,mycols].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
# there are cases where an SC has only one NETWORK_CELLID so there is no combination
# make tuple to itself in this situation
dfd = ( dfdd.groupby("SC").agg({"NETWORK_CELLID":
                                lambda s: list(itertools.combinations(list(s), 2))
                               if len(list(s))>1 else [tuple(list(s)*2)]})
    # generate rows for each pair
    .explode("NETWORK_CELLID").rename({"NETWORK_CELLID":"PAIR"}, axis=1).reset_index()
    # split pairs of locations back into individual column s
    .assign(n1=lambda dfa: dfa["PAIR"].apply(lambda s: s[0]),
            n2=lambda dfa: dfa["PAIR"].apply(lambda s: s[1]))
    # merge back original data so have lat/lon for the pair of locations
    .merge(dfdd, left_on=["SC","n1"], right_on=["SC","NETWORK_CELLID"]).drop("NETWORK_CELLID", axis=1)
    .merge(dfdd, left_on=["SC","n2"], right_on=["SC","NETWORK_CELLID"]).drop("NETWORK_CELLID", axis=1)
    # finally calc the distance
    .assign(miles=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: 
                                           geopy.distance.geodesic((r["Lat_x"],r["Lon_x"]), 
                                                                   (r["Lat_y"],r["Lon_y"])).miles, axis=1)) 
      )
```

Comment: thank you very much @Rob Raymond. When I execute the code with my data, I am having **'float' object is not subscriptable error** while **split pairs of locations back into individual column s**. I noticed that my string data is not left justified as yours, might it be the reason?

Comment: I don't think so,  more likely its not formed a pair because of source data issues where a pair isn't formed.  the code doesn't defensively check that the tuple is of length 2 hence using `[0]` and `[1]` slices could fail.  Happy to try your data if you can provide as a shared file somewhere.

Comment: many thanks indeed. As you will notice, **NETWORK_CELLID, SC, Lat, Lon** are the needed columns 
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hpn8VisQAJFJb7Q2lQi2hNLQYZUF6dV7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @NAMIKISIK interesting edge case...  have provided a supplementary update.  This case does not occur it you don't de-dup first !  I'm getting 3420 combinations after this.  You can identify these edge cases where n1==n2 and miles will be zero

Comment: thank you for the quick reply and amazing information. I would appreciate if you could recommend data analysis references for Python that will help to improve myself.

Comment: I've only been working with python/pandas for last year... but have 25 years of working with data and data quality.... tech is the easy bit,  6th sense of how to structure and analyse data comes with experience !  hence my sense that there was an edge case where a pair could not be formed